# I am trying to make a "robot" appear to be talking on my website. The mouth must sync with sound and I am thinking....flash?

Tags: flash, dynamic, audio, equalizer

I have seen that some websites offer talking characters (very human looking avatars), but I do not want to pay HUGE money for those.  So I started thinking about some of the cartoons I used to watch and if there was a talking computer, their way of visually portraying speech was with an equalizer.

For the "robot", I would just have 2 dots for the eyes, a nose, and a "mouth", but this mouth would really be an equalizer, and I could animate that with flash so that when there is loud sound, the mouth would open wider than it would for a soft sound ( if you watch an equalizer, the bars go way up and turn red when the music is loud, and remain low and green when sound is soft )

The only web technology that I imagine could do such a thing is flash, but I know very very little flash.  I have been searching and searching and searching and all of the equalizer tutorials I have found are just bars with random movements that do not sync with the audio.  Can I sync audio and flash to make an equalizer?

Comment: The biggest issue is *getting sound in* (I am presuming by a microphone? please correct if wrong) -- Flash or Silverlight (at least 4) can both do this (with user permission). After an audio-stream has been acquired it's just a simple cause->effect. (A signed applet also might, but I'd avoid that route at all costs.)

Comment: Hi.  thanks for answering.  I have had experience using a few flash apps, and in those, I have been able to pass in an xml file (like for a photo slideshow), thus the flash app (the slideshow) was dynamic.  I would like to do something like this, only I would pass in an mp3 file.  I would like the flash app (which is essentially only a line that moves ) to react dynamically to the mp3.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the sound spectrum use SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(), this will fill a supplied array with 512 values (256 for each channel, left & right), ranging from -1 to 1. I use this to draw the little bars to show that sound is being sent. I create a Timer so it is called a couple times a second and it makes for a great effect.

To get what you want really easily you could draw a 512 px horizontal line, each px being a value from the array, then scale vertically accordingily to how big you want the flash app to appear (e.g. multiply the value by 100 to get a 200px high movie).

Here's an example I did a few years ago http://lakehousemusic.net/player/index.html?num=3

Comment: wow Chris, that is really nice!  And very clever!  Thank you so much for this!